# Make text responsive

Tags: css, mobile, text, typography

I made a script and now I want the text to be responsive. (Re sizes on different resolutions) There is a random background js also (If it affects the process).

Here is the CSS:

> Removed, This will be used commercially and does not affect the answer :)

Thanks ...

Comment: Define “responsive”. It has some technical meanings, and it’s also used as a meaningless or ambiguous buzzword.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use px for font-size, but em or rem ... look here http://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

Comment: I tried again and it worked, THANKS!! - What is the best size for the background??